Problem with passing variables between Python and Fortran using F2py
I have been attempting to call a simple Fortran subroutine from python using f2py without success. The Fortran subroutine just adds two numbers defined in the python code. The Fortran code is:
C
      SUBROUTINE TESTLIB(A,B,C)
C
      REAL, intent (in) :: A, B
      REAL, intent (out) :: C
      C = A + B
      END SUBROUTINE TESTLIB  

Python:
import numpy as np
import testlib2

A = 3
B = 2
C = testlib2.testlib(A, B)
print("C = ", C)
 

I created testlib2.pyd file from the command line with
python -m numpy.f2py -c -m testlib2 testlib2.f

Then placed testlib2.pyd file in the same directory as the python file (testlib.py). I had to install meson, ninja, cmake, charset-normalizer and pkgconfig libraries to make F2py work with Python 3.12.
When I run the python code testlib.py (Spyder 5.5) I receive the following error:
  File c:\users\bcn\documents\hps\hps fortran\testlib.py:6
    C = testlib2.testlib(A, B)

TypeError: testlib2.testlib() missing required argument 'c' (pos 3).

The call to the Fortran subroutine appears to requiring the C variable to be defined but has been defined as an "out" variable. Not sure why it is doing this. The examples I have seen indicate that the Fortran subroutine needs to have the out variable listed. Using Windows 11 and Python 3.12. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

It is not a real issue, byt why would you write new Fortran 90+ code in the fixed form in the 21st century? I would even go as far as trying the same in a free form source file. Perhaps, for some strange reasons, pyf requires the additional comment directives in the fixed form...

I tested your code and it works as expected with Python 3.11 and f2py 1.26.4 on OpenSUSE Linux. Please show more details about your software versions and configurations. Try to do all steps in a single directory. Probably just copying the .pyd file is problematic.

The signature of the Fortran code and that used by the python code should be the same.  You are specifying a procedure with one return value.  The equivalent in python would be
testlib2.testlib(A, B, C)

In python, unless you're dealing with objects, the parameters do not change.  The intent is always IN.  To make the signatures the same, change testlib to a function
C
      REAL FUNCTION TESTLIB(A,B)
C
      REAL, intent (in) :: A, B
      TESTLIB = A + B
      END FUNCTION TESTLIB 


This really should not be necessary. The original code from the answer should work exactly as it is presented. And it does, in fact, work for me.
